# Kindda-Perfect number: Is there a sequence of numbers which are equal to the sum of its proper divisors excluding itself as well as 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, perfect-numbers

[Perfect number](https://www.britannica.com/topic/perfect-number) is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its proper divisors. The smallest perfect number is 6, which is the sum of 1, 2, and 3.

Is there a sequence of numbers which are equal to the sum of its proper divisors **excluding itself as well as 1**?

If yes, what are they called? Name first few numbers in the sequence.

Is there a general formula for them?

Please provide with some link to read more.

Comment: Checked up to 1500, there are none. Several length two cycles, though, like $48\mapsto75\mapsto48$, $140\mapsto195\mapsto140$, $1050\mapsto1925\mapsto1050$, ...

Comment: Checked up to $10^6$ in a few seconds with this Sage one-liner and there are none: `[n for n in srange(1, 10^6+1) if sigma(n) == 2*n+1]`. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Such an abundant number with abundance 1 is called a **quasiperfect** number (which is a more professional way to say "kindda-perfect"). None have been found, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiperfect_number). This [1982 article](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/some-results-concerning-quasiperfect-numbers/773348EC71E156E2E460DCC03D55030D) says that *if a quasiperfect number exists, it must be an odd square number greater than $10^{35}$ and have at least seven distinct prime factors.* A recent article on this topic is [here.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01063)

Comment: It states, "A quasiperfect number is a natural number n for which the sum of all its divisors is equal to 2n + 1. Equivalently, n is the sum of its non-trivial divisors (that is, its divisors excluding 1 and 'n')." But I am looking for a number for which the sum of most of its divisors is itself.

Comment: that's what it is, right? you want $n$ to be the sum of all of its divisors excluding 1 and excluding itself.

Comment: For a number n, their sum is equal to 2n+1.

Comment: $2n+1$ is if you do not exclude $n$ as divisor; if you do, the sum is $n+1$, and if you also exclude $1$ (which is what you want), the sum is $n$ --- or am I missing something obvious here???

Comment: Oh I missed that.